# How to mutate data in Strapi with a site made with Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby, static-site, strapi, headless-cms

I wanted to know if it's possible to write mutation querys in a site made with gatsby. The data I want to create in Strapi will not be used to display new information, it will just store data.

Is there any approach to do this? From what I've read, Gatsby by itself won't mutate Strapi data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need provide ApolloClient to your website. The best way will be in your root in gatsby-ssr.js  and  gatsby-browser.js after that you can use `react-apollo` like in bellow examples

### client.js

```
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost"

const token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZDRhN2FlNjRlYzE1MzIxMTY0N2EzNWMiLCJpc0FkbWluIjp0cnVlLCJpYXQiOjE1NjU1OTI2ODcsImV4cCI6MTU2ODE4NDY4N30.FZIWJ7sWhmQo6MPgUbY2Js-uVMWY1kUdASvr2oyY6Sd"
const url = "http://localhost:1337"

export default new ApolloClient({
  uri: `${url}/graphql`,
  request: operation => {
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
  },
})
```

### gatsby-ssr.js  and  gatsby-browser.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { client } from './src/client';

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    {element}
  </ApolloProvider>
);
```

### postTemplate.js

```
import React from "react"
import { Mutation } from "react-apollo"
import gql from "graphql-tag"

const POST_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation PostMutation($description: String!, $url: String!) {
    post(description: $description, url: $url) {
      id
      createdAt
      url
      description
    }
  }
`
const PostTemplate = () => {
  const description = "example description"
  const url = "url"

  return (
    <Mutation mutation={POST_MUTATION} variables={{ description, url }}>
      {() => <button onClick={"... you'll implement this "}>Submit</button>}
    </Mutation>
  )
}

Export default PostTemplate
```

Other links

- [similar guthub issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/9406)
- [howtographql.com/react-apollo#muttation](https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/3-mutations-creating-links/)